# Run `rails db:migrate` with capistrano in a gem/submodule

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, capistrano, git-submodules

I have a rails 5.2 app. I am trying to deploy it using Capistrano.

The app has a gem dependency submodule, which contains all of the models and migrations needed for this project. This submodule depends on other gems in it's `.gemspec`.

Therefore, I need to run `rails db:migrate` in the submodule root, instead of the parent project root.

I have added the following to `deploy.rb`:

```
  desc 'Runs rake db:migrate if migrations are set'
  task :migrate => [:set_rails_env] do
    on primary fetch(:migration_role) do
      within "#{release_path}/PATH/TO/SUBMODULE" do
        with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
          execute :rake, "db:migrate"
        end
      end
    end
  end

  before :starting,    :migrate
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'dependency', path: 'PATH/TO/SUBMODULE'
gem 'capistrano-git-with-submodules', '~> 2.0'
group :development do
  gem 'capistrano',         require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rvm',     require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rails',   require: false
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', require: false
  gem 'capistrano3-puma',   require: false
end
```

When I try to run this task, I get an error message saying:

```
 DEBUG [b4c1cf18]   [31mCould not find aasm-5.0.2 in any of the sources[0m
 DEBUG [b4c1cf18]   
 DEBUG [b4c1cf18]   [33mRun `bundle install` to install missing gems.[0m
 DEBUG [b4c1cf18]
```

It seems like the gem set (containing all parent and submodule gems) used in deploying the parent project isn't in the path or is unavailable when it comes time to run this task.

I can get the parent project running without the migrations, so I know that the parent project is loading all the correct gem set at runtime. Just not during this task.

I'm not quite sure how Capistrano works under the hood, how could I make sure that these gems are available to this task when it runs?

Comment: All the gems I've used just copy the migrations to the project's db/migrate folder. Is your gem a custom one? The error is not related to the migrations though, it says it can't find aasm-5.0.2, login to your server and run bundle install on your project's root and make sure it ends successfully.

Comment: @arieljuod yes it's a custom gem, and yes it can bundle them successfully, just not during this task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I needed 3 things:

1.`execute :bundle` before `execute :rake, :"db:migrate"`

2. Provide a second argument to `within "#{release_path}/PATH/TO/SUBMODULE"` to make it `within "#{release_path}/PATH/TO/SUBMODULE", release_path` - couldn't find docs on this, only this PR: https://github.com/capistrano/bundler/pull/84
3. symlink secrets to the engine so it doesn't prevent any tasks from running:

```
    task :symlink_secrets do
        on roles(:app) do
          execute "rm -rf #{release_path}/PATH/TO/SUBMODULE/spec/dummy/config/secrets.yml"
          execute "ln -nfs ~/secrets.yml #{release_path}/PATH/TO/SUBMODULE/spec/dummy/config/secrets.yml"
        end 
    end
```